# ng-attr where the attribute has a dash

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to use angular to evaluate an attribute value. The catch is that this attribute value has a dash (-).

In short, I need:

```
<div ng-attr-my-attribute="{{5+5}}"></div>
```

To render into:

```
<div my-attribute="10"></div>
```

What actually happens is the DOM just shows this verbatim:

```
<div ng-attr-my-attribute="{{5+5}}"></div>
```

I feel like I need to use ng-attr because when I don't, for example:

```
<div my-attribute="{{5+5}}"></div>
```

renders exactly as:

```
<div my-attribute="{{5+5}}"></div>
```

Using angular 1.4.1

Question: How to use `ng-attr` with an attribute that has a dash in it?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: using ng-attr with an attribute that has a dash in it

Answer (score -1):

> On some case, For example, SVG DOM API's restrictions, you cannot
>   simply write cx="{{scope_var}}".

`ng-attr` only required if there is  **restriction** on DOM API else you can use direct attribute. For `div` and other standard HTML element,  you can direct access attribute without using `ng-attr`.

`ng-attr` work fine with `-`

Check snippet:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <p>Check value in browser inspect for div attribute</p>
  <div my-attribute="{{5+5}}"></div>
  <div ng-attr-my-attribute="{{5+5}}"></div>
  <svg>
    <circle cx="{{5+5}}"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```